# Getting Tab parameters inside LaunchConfigurationDelegate

Tags: eclipse-plugin, launch-configuration

I have a custom launch configuration. It currently has a JavaArgumentsTab() where I can enter things for VM arguments and Program arguments. But how do I actually get any values entered there?

Ideally I would get them inside my LaunchConfigurationDelegate's launch() method. I expected to find any text entered as arguments inside the LaunchConfiguration or other parameters to that method, and I'm sure this is a newbie question, but I really haven't found anything promising.

TabGroup:

```java
public class LaunchConfigurationTabGroup extends AbstractLaunchConfigurationTabGroup {

@Override
public void createTabs(ILaunchConfigurationDialog dialog, String mode) {
    ILaunchConfigurationTab[] tabs = new ILaunchConfigurationTab[] {
            new JavaArgumentsTab(),
            new CommonTab()
    };
    setTabs(tabs);
} }
```

LaunchConfigurationDelegate:

```java
public class LaunchConfigurationDelegate implements ILaunchConfigurationDelegate {

@Override
public void launch(ILaunchConfiguration configuration, String mode,
        ILaunch launch, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
    // How to get anything entered on my Java tab here...?

} }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything from the tabs should already have been set as attribute values in the `ILaunchConfiguration` when `launch` is called.

The settings from `JavaArgumentsTab` are stored in the attributes using constants from `IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants`.

Comment: OK yes, the string value is contained in configuration.getAttribute(IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_PROGRAM_ARGUMENTS, ""); Thank you!